# Why alpine os baseed zulu OpenJDK container image can pass env with dot or dashes but ubuntu os based image not

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, alpine-linux

I'm using alpine os based OpenJDK `mcr.microsoft.com/java/jre-headless:8u242-zulu-alpine` image, see [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-java-jre-headless?tab=description), then in k8s, I can create a deployment, pass some envs, the env variables can contains dot or dashes, like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jdktest
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jdktest
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jdktest
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
          - name: spring.application.name
            value: myname
          - name: spring-test
            value: mytest
          name: jdktest
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/java/jre-headless:8u242-zulu-alpine
          command:
          - /bin/sh
          - -c
          args:
          - 'sleep 100000'
```

exec into the container, then I can get env like this:

```
/ # env | grep spring
spring.application.name=myname
spring-test=mytest
```

But if I export env with dot/dashes in the container,

```
/ # export spring.test1=value
sh: export: spring.test1: bad variable name
```

==============================================================

Now I update the OpenJDK with ubuntu os based,

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jdktest
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jdktest
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jdktest
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
          - name: spring.application.name
            value: myname
          - name: spring-test
            value: mytest
          name: jdktest
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/java/jre-headless:8u242-zulu-ubuntu  # only change here
          command:
          - /bin/sh
          - -c
          args:
          - 'sleep 100000'
```

But now I can't pass env variables with dot and dashes, see

```
# env | grep spring
#
```

I also cannot export env with dot/dashes in the container

```
# export spring.test1=value
sh: 8: export: spring.test1: bad variable name
```

Now I want to change the image with ubuntu based, how can I migrate it smoothly? must I update the env names?(update dot/dashes to underscore)?

Comment: Probably because the Alpine-based image uses BusyBox for its `/bin/sh` implementation, but in Ubuntu it will be either dash or GNU bash.  POSIX.1 [defines a NAME](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_235) to consist only of ASCII letters, numbers, and underscores, but not periods.

Comment: thanks, but why when I exec into `8u242-zulu-alpine` container, I can't export env variables with dot/dashes, it's a little confused to me

Comment: To bring this back to a _programming_ discussion, setting arbitrary Spring items using the environment is much easier using [`- name: SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.3/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.application-json) or its `SPRING_APPLICATION_YAML` friend